# How to add strings to a url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need help in adding strings to the url:

```
Ex : mydomain.com/categoryname
to : mydomain.com/category-list/categoryname
I try: RewriteRule ^(.*)/.{0}$ category-list/$1 [R=301], but this not working.
```

My English is not good, 
Hope everyone sympathize,
Thanks all.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your rule.  I think you want `category-list` instead of `categorylist`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I want to add category-list in url, how to do this?

Comment: do you have rewrite logging turned on? If so what do you see in the log file.  I suspect your rule is resulting in an url of `category-list/` or maybe `category-list/mydomain.com`. But that's just a guess. Logging would tell you for sure.

Comment: No, i don't. 
Is there a way to rewrite the url as I want, thanks.
I try rewrite in htaccess but result like : mydomain.com/category-list/category-list/category-list ...